# Migrating script from C to PHP

Tags: php, c

I'm migrating a script from C to PHP (http://svn.stellman-greene.com/mgrs_to_utm/trunk/) and I have a problem with this concept in [mgrs_to_utm.c](http://svn.stellman-greene.com/mgrs_to_utm/trunk/mgrs_to_utm.c):

```
Letters[0] = (toupper(MGRS[j]) - (long)'A');
if ((Letters[0] == LETTER_I) || (Letters[0] == LETTER_O))
```

`MGRS[j]` is a part of string, but WTF I can substract a `(long)'A'` to a `LETTER`??

`LETTER_I` is an integer (defined in [mgrs_to_utm.h](http://svn.stellman-greene.com/mgrs_to_utm/trunk/mgrs_to_utm.h)).

I have in mind PHP and I can't found the logic to this operation.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: that looks like an ASCii substraction to adjust a value in the array letter

Comment: I don't know about the typecasting to `LONG` but this is actually very common to convert a letter from ASCII to the number of the letter in the alphabet. Characters are just normal integers, so having a `char c` it's okay to do `toupper(c) - 'A'`.

Comment: `ord(strtoupper(MGRS[j])) - ord('A')` I think, this php is equivalent to that `c` code. But note from manual, it won't always return US-ASCII value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASCII, the character 'A' has value 65, so Letters[0] effectively contains an offset into the alphabet (A being 0).

If MGRS[j] is 'I' (73) then we take 'A' (65) from it to leave 8

```
A B C D E F G H I J K...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The code is pretty much the same as:

```
if ( MGRS[j] == 'I' || MGRS[j] == 'O' || MGRS[j] == 'i' || MGRS[j] == 'o')
```

Comment: Ok :) A PHP implement would be `$Letters[0] = ord(strtoupper($MGRS[$j])) - ord('A'); if (($Letters[0] == $LETTER_I) || ($Letters[0] == $LETTER_O)) {`...

Using ord PHP function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php.

I can understand now the rest of code :)

Comment: Beware that the value of the letter is actually used in calculation in a couple places: `grid_northing = (double)(letters[2]) * ONEHT + false_northing; grid_easting = (double)((letters[1]) - ltr2_low_value + 1) * ONEHT;`. To get the value, I would do `intval($letters[2], 36) - 10`.